# How to apply 2 OR and 1 AND condition in code igniter in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I've made a utility where user either has to type his roll number or mobile number to get access to private area, but i also want him to be member of that private area, so how can i write a active record query to archive this. Previously i tried this query

```
$where = "member='1' AND rollnumber='".$num."' OR mobile='".$number."'";
$this->db->where($where);
```

1 representing part of that group, as i said i tried and I get Database ERROR

> Unknown column 'member=1' in 'where clause'

note: query should be like this

```
(member == 1) AND (rollnumber = $num OR mobile = $num)
```

Comment: It seems like you don't have a column in your table called `member`?

Comment: show your full query and also table schema

Comment: table scheme 
table name : student
column name : student_name, member, rollnumber, mobile, age

Comment: @avinashizhere i mean all post all details generated by `DESCRIBE student` using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

What's happening in your case, is CodeIgniter is trying to escape the field names and is failing, thus generating faulty SQL.

You can pass an associative array to `where` instead of crafting your own string.  As for the `OR`, you can use `or_where`.

```
$this->db->where(array(
    'member' => 1,
    'rollnumber' => $num
))->or_where('mobile', $number);
```

This will generate the following:

```
WHERE member = 1 AND rollnumber = $num OR mobile = $number
```

---

**NOTE**:  Because of how MySQL handles `AND`/`OR`, this query might not run as you want.  It's gonna be interpreted as:

```
(member = 1 AND rollnumber = $num) OR mobile = $number
```

I assume that's not what you want.  I assume you want:

```
member = 1 AND (rollnumber = $num OR mobile = $number)
```

This cannot be done *nicely* in CodeIgniter.  You need to build your own WHERE clause like you were trying in the question.

Try something like this:

```
$numbers = '(rollnumber = '.$this->db->escape($num).' OR mobile = '.$this->db->escape($number).')';

$this->db->where('member', 1)->where($numbers, NULL, FALSE);
```

The key here is the `FALSE` as the 3rd parameter to `where()`.  This tells CodeIgniter not to try and escape your field names.

This will correctly generate:

```
member = 1 AND (rollnumber = $num OR mobile = $number)
```

Comment: pardon my question writing skills it's like (member == 1) AND (rollnumber = $num OR mobile = $num)

Comment: @avinashizhere: Yes, that is what I assume you want.  I added more info about that to the answer just now.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your replies, i kinda tried new thing to find the solution and i was successfully, according to the question, i applied this solution

```
$this->db->where('rollnumber',$num);
$this->db->or_where('mobile',$num);
$query = $this->db->get_where('student',array('member'=>1));
```

and it did the trick :)